# Binding ItemsControl with WrapPanel?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've set my ItemsControl with WrapPanel as:

```
            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Height="200" Width="420" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="itemsMarks" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                    <Image Margin="1"  
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Source="Images/markg.png"
                                Width="70"
                                Height="70" />
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding timestamp}" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         </ItemsControl>
```

my data is

```
    private class mark_item
    {
        public mark_item()
        {
            this.timestamp= "";
        }
        public string timestamp { get; set; }
    }

    private List<mark_item> marks;

    itemsMarks.ItemsSource = marks;
```

List marks is properly created, and WrapPanel contains actually the number of items there are in the list, but TextBlock doesn't get its Text property set.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't created a proper binding between your `ItemsControl` and your list data. Setting the `ItemsSource` property is not enough.

Comment: if you debug your app you should see some binding warnings coming up in the Output windows in visual studio, could you post one of thoes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your `mark_item` class as `public`, not `private`.

Data binding in Silverlight can only access `public` classes and properties.  By declaring the class `private`, you're preventing Silverlight from being able to access it.

I took your code as it is and I saw the same behaviour you described.  The right number of items were appearing in the `ItemsControl` but the text was missing. I also saw the following message in the Output window in Visual Studio/Visual Web Developer Express.  (I've omitted the stacktrace as the message itself is long enough):

> System.Windows.Data Error: Cannot get 'timestamp' value (type 'System.String') from 'PrivateClassProblem.MainPage+mark_item' (type 'PrivateClassProblem.MainPage+mark_item'). BindingExpression: Path='timestamp' DataItem='PrivateClassProblem.MainPage+mark_item' (HashCode=12905972); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String').. System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'System.Windows.CLRPropertyListener.get_Value()' to access method 'PrivateClassProblem.MainPage+mark_item.get_timestamp()' failed.

When I declared the class `public`, the problem went away.